# Uses for a storage driver filter

Tags: windows, driver, filter-driver

I’m a freshman computer science student, and wanted to know what is possible with a storage driver filter. For the project I am working on, I would need to slow down a hard drive or ssd. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can write a disk filter driver and slow down io packets processing (IRPs).

Comment: Would that be an upper level filter driver or lower level one?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: probably you need to add your speed controlling code on IRP_MJ_READ and IRP_MJ_WRITE. disk upper filter should be ok.